# Eclipse OSGi (Kura) Plugin and Maven

Tags: eclipse, maven, osgi-bundle, kura

I have a simple basic question. If I develop plugin for Kura in eclipse with maven, can I use dependency feature of Maven? I mean, when I use Maven for my Spring projects, I simple add dependency to pom.xml file and I can use in my project. Since I run Spring project on my local machine, dependent .jar files can be used runtime. This time, I will deploy my plugin to another device (Raspberry) , I have to put everything in the bundle .jar package. Can Maven do this or should I add dependent .jar files to classpath manualy?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [maven shade plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) to build the so called *uber-jar* - one jar that will contain your project along with all the dependencies.